i am trying to binary training session with TabNetClassifier
[error on binary training session study case ddos classification with tabnet]
Binary Configuration

fit_params_0_b = dict(
    X_train = X_train_b, y_train = y_train_b.values,
    eval_set = [(X_val_b, y_val_b.values)], patience = 10, max_epochs = 200,
    eval_metric = ["logloss"], eval_name = ["Validation"],
    compute_importance = True, batch_size = 16384, virtual_batch_size = 1024,
    num_workers = 0, drop_last = False, pin_memory = True, warm_start = False)]

Binary Training Session
clf_0_b.fit(**fit_params_0_b)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-163-0c6a65839c90> in <cell line: 14>()
     12 
     13 # Now call the fit method
---> 14 clf_0_b.fit(**fit_params_0_b)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py in log_loss(y_true, y_pred, eps, normalize, sample_weight, labels)
   2868     if len(lb.classes_) == 1:
   2869         if labels is None:
-> 2870             raise ValueError(
   2871                 "y_true contains only one label ({0}). Please "
   2872                 "provide the true labels explicitly through the "

ValueError: y_true contains only one label (0). Please provide the true labels explicitly through the labels argument.


This is not a minimal reproducible example. It is not clear what clf_0_b is (I can only assume this is a TabNetClassifier whatever that may be). The error you are getting seems quite instructive though. You should explicitly provide a labels argument.
